# Android Studio And Ethereum?

Tags: dapps, ganache, android

how i can connect android studio application with Ganache? i'm trying to build an application on android (that is my Front end) with a Smart contract (Back end) on my private Blockchain (Ganache). it's possible to do it? there are any other methods to do this?

Comment: Ganache server is like any other HTTP server, so as long as your Android emulator can connect to your localhost, it should be fine.

Comment: So i just need to take my Android Emulator connect it with my local server (ganache) and interact with it with my front end?

Comment: Yes. You most likely want to use web3j or other Java library. Under the hood, the communication with Ganache or any Ethereum server is just a HTTP connection.